# SharePoint Search and Columns with HTML

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results

We are using SharePoint Search to index data from our SharePoint list.
We have one column which contains HTML characters but finding that the results coming back from the FullTextSQLQuery object have only text and do not have the HTML characters.

Can someone clarify whether or not SharePoint Search supports HTML characters?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint ignores the HTML in the content it indexes.  Generally HTML is not considered content that is relevant to the user so it doesn't include it.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/18d559f2-3ebb-4594-abe5-e5e218d86348/